# How many bits are used for the exponent

Tags: c++, floating-point, fixed-point

I'm writing a few functions that will convert float/double to fixed point and back. Does anyone know the best way to determine the number of bits used for the exponent portion of a float or double? I was hoping to using something from std::numeric_limits, but have had no luck.

Is the exponent part defined by the C++ standard or is it compiler/machine specific? Or can it vary at runtime?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `float` on that platform is encoded in IEC-559 (a.k.a. IEEE 754 in the United States), then it will always be 8 bits. If the `double` of that platform is encoded with IEC-559 (or whatever the 64 bit version is) then it will always be 11. If not, then you can't even assume it stores the exponent.

While the Standard doesn't specify in what format floating point numbers should be stored, in C++11 (and C++03?) you can test if `float` or `double` conforms to IEC-559 by using `numeric_limits<T>::is_iec559` (where `T` is a floating-point type):

```
#include <limits>

cout << "float is IEC-559?  " << numeric_limits<float>::is_iec559 << endl
     << "double is IEC-559? " << numeric_limits<double>::is_iec559 << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

What is missing from numeric_limits<>::{min_exponent, max_exponent}? (They are constrained to give the answer for normalized numbers, if that doesn't suit you, combine with `denorm` and `digits`).

Answer (score 0):

Read up on [IEEE-754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985).  The exponent sizes for `float` and `double` should be 8 and 11 bits, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

The characteristics of floating point numbers depend on the machine architecture. It does not vary at runtime. Have a look at the header <[cfloat](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cfloat/)> of your compiler, it should have the details.

But you can also dive into the machine yourself:
The book *Numerical Recipes in C* by W.H. Press et al. contains a program named `machar.c` in chapter 20.1 (Less-numerical algorithms) to detect the machine's floating point capabilities without assuming anything from standard library headers. It's also available [online](http://nr.com).